# How to leave spaces between views in android

Tags: android

### Below there are two row views .......... How to leave a space between them i mean blank space between Views

- What code do i need to add between the rows
- I am not speaking abot padding between the rows, ......... I am
  trying to achieve Blank space between
- I am trying to achieve this in relative layout not grid layout

**Any Ideas**

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2sp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TimingsID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Timings"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/BuyReservedButtonRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2sp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BuyButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: You can't add code to XML.  You can add data, such as definitions for new views and attributes for existing ones.  Which views do you want o have space between?  The TableRows?

Comment: @Sky why not just add an empty View?

Comment: @ Marci Căşvan ......... How did i not think about this ..... Your solution works and its efficient to compatible with lower level API's too :)

Comment: @ Marci Căşvan .............. I got an answer given by `user2652394` as one of the answers to this question ..... There is a much simpler solution by using an empty linear layout  + padding for it ...... I just wanted to share this info with you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your table-row like this, you can leave any space you need:

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2sp" >
        <!-- HERE IS THE THING YOU NEED -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TimingsID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Timings"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- MAKE SPACE AS MUCH AS YOU WANT, 20DP FOR EXAMPLE -->
    </TableRow>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sweet answer !..... This was what i was exactly looking for !......... Your solution is much simple and Fesable ... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use Space view between them like this

```
    <Space
    android:id="@+id/space1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp" />
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for solution , but it only works with API level-14 ...... any solution if its for lower level API's ?

Comment: you can use it from support lib android.support.v7.widget.Space

Comment: I am trying for a relative layout not grid layout ... please look at the updated question

Comment: @ kalyanpvs ............ I have accepted your solution as its a working one but ......... We can just use a many textview's in collection repeatedly to achieve the goal for lower lever API's :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout as well:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2sp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TimingsID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Timings"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/BuyReservedButtonRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2sp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BuyButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need are margins like `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"`. Because in your code you already use `padding`, so I assume you know what happens if you use it. A margin will add some room around your View, depends on which margin you will use.

Try this:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="2sp"


    android:marginBottom="10dp"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TimingsID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Timings"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/BuyReservedButtonRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="2sp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BuyButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: I tried adding ... but it allows only few spaces between the rows ......Im trying to leave more space like .... say hmmmm 7 rows ..... how to do so , Any ideas ?

Comment: OK, please update your question with a better description of your needs. Because it will be pure luck if you get the right solution.